# Is it possible to use the firefox password manager to launch safe mode/deafult profile?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm new in firefox-webextensions and I want to create an extension that protects my profile so, if the master password entered at start is wrong, then restart and launch default profile or safe mode.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The passwords stored in logins.json are encrypted, but the encryption key is stored in key4.db (previously in key3.db) and without a master password you merely need to place the two files is Firefox profile folder to see the passwords in the Password Manager.

The usernames and passwords are encrypted with triple-DES stored in the key file, but the MP adds an extra layer.

https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/security/nss/doc/html/pk12util.html